# How to properly create a new type whith a custom behaviour of isinstance?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, typechecking

I would like to have for exemple a `posint` class that inherit from `int`, but with a custom behaviour when calling `isinstance()`:

```
>>> isinstance(1, int), isinstance(1, posint)
(True, True)
>>> isinstance(-1, int), isinstance(-1, posint)
(True, False)
```

I tried first:

```
class posint(int):

    def __instancecheck__(self, obj):
        try:
            obj >= 0
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

But the `__instancecheck__` have to be declared in a metaclass.

So I end up with this heavy and ugly thing:

```
class NewType(type):

    def __instancecheck__(self, obj):
        try:
            obj >= 0
            return True
        except:
            return False

class posint(metaclass=NewType):
    pass
```

It works, but it cannot be the good solution... Doesn't work with any other checking, doesn't support inheritance...

After that I managed to implement something better:

```
class CheckedType(type):

    def __instancecheck__(cls, obj):
        if not all(isinstance(obj, base) for base in cls.mro()[1:-1]):
            return False
        return cls.__instancecheck__(obj)

class posint(int, metaclass=CheckedType):

    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, obj):
        if obj >= 0:
            return True
        return False
```

But this seems an abuse of `__instancecheck__`.
I was thinking we can use use something from the `abc` or the `typing` module...

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that this class should actually be a subclass of `int`.

Comment: If you want to inherit of all the methods of `int`, you should...

Comment: Here's the thing. Inheriting methods from `int` only matters if you're going to create concrete instances of this class, and if you're going to do that, your class is mixing responsibilities it shouldn't. On one hand, your class is supposed to act as a way to check for positive-int-ness, with `isinstance(5, posint)`. On the other hand, concrete instances of your class are going to behave differently from regular positive `int`s, perhaps prohibiting `posint(5) - posint(6)`, or if they behave identically, there's no reason to create such instances.

Comment: If concrete instances of your class behave differently from regular positive `int`s, it's going to be important to be able to distinguish them from regular positive `int`s, but `isinstance` can't do that job, because you changed how it behaves. Your class is going to be unnecessarily confusing because it's trying to play two subtly contradictory roles at once.

Comment: In reality it's for an ohter use wich is not related to the question... I don't want this class to have instances : it's a matter of autocompletion with variable annotations (new in python 3.6). For exemaple you have a class Circle with a radius. You write in the class body : `radius: posint`. If your `posint` inherit with from int, you will have all the methods of `int` proposed in your IDE (or in vim with jedi-vim). So maybe I need to make an ABC after all...

Comment: How does your IDE treat `typing.NewType`? It sounds to me like `NewType`  will do most of what you want, maybe requiring some helper functions.

Comment: I thought about it. But, from what I saw in the documentation, I wasn't able to guess how to enable typechecking with... If you have a solution using that, I would like to see it!

Comment: It's not looking great, to be honest. It looks like Jedi doesn't do anything with NewType currently, and it wasn't even mentioned in the documentation, regarding what it does and doesn't handle. I tried making something from your requirements, and it was mostly the same, although I ended up writing a `__new__` method on the subclass to be a validating cast.

Comment: Yes jedi doesn't handle `NewType`, but it can do it with an `int` subclass. For example `class subint(int): pass`. When you have it as an annotation of `x` in a class body, it will show you the `int` methods at the `x` attribute of its instances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A this time, after some experimentations, I'm using this recipe:

```
class TypedMeta(type):
    """Metaclass used for custom types."""

    def __instancecheck__(cls, obj):
        return cls._test(obj)

    @staticmethod
    def _init(self, x):
        if not self._test(x):
            raise ValueError(f"bad value for '{self.__class__.__name__}' object")

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        if not clsdict.get('_test'):
            raise TypeError(f"cannot instaciate '{name}' class without '_test' method")
        setattr(cls, '__init__', TypedMeta._init)


class posint(int, metaclass=TypedMeta):
    """Strictly positive 'int'."""

    @classmethod
    def _test(cls, val):
        return val > 0
```

So even if somebody wants to instantiate an object of this type, or to cast another into it, it will perform the `_test` method first.